can two methods with same name with same parameter can be used in java
//using the concept of method overloading
public class practice10 {


        // Method to calculate the area of a rectangle
        public static double calculateArea(double length, double width) {
            return length * width;
        }

        // Method to calculate the area of a square
        public static double calculateArea(double side) {
            return side * side;
        }

        // Method to calculate the area of a circle
        public static double calculateArea(double radius) {
            return Math.PI * radius * radius;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Calculate and display the area of a rectangle
            System.out.println("Area of rectangle (length=5, width=4): " + calculateArea(5.0, 4.0));

            // Calculate and display the area of a square
            System.out.println("Area of square (side=4): " + calculateArea(4.0));

            // Calculate and display the area of a circle
            System.out.println("Area of circle (radius=3): " + calculateArea(3.0));
        }
}

i took this code from chatGPT it was showing no error in this but when i complied this program error was occured.

duplicating a method is not the same as overloading. An overloaded method takes different parameters. No. this can't work.

Note: chatGPT not necessarily produces correct code - you still need to think for yourself :) - Now put yourself into the shoes of the Java runtime - which method would calculateArea(1.23) refer to?

pls can u tell me what to do next

have you checked the already posted answers?

yes i have go through all answer

@Pankaj so what else do you need to know?

"... can be used in java" + "error was occured" (depending on WHICH error) == NO, it cannot || How should the compiler known which method to call; that calculateArea(4.0) is not the same method as calculateArea(3.0) ?

For overloaded methods, either the method name, the number of parameters or the type of parameters must be different. The compiled bytecode won't see the names you've given the parameters, so it doesn't see the last two as different.

@NickGris "For overloaded methods, either the method name, ... must be different". No. If the methods have different names, they are not overloaded. Overloaded methods are methods that differ (only) in number or type of parameters

@Stultuske: That's true. In my head I was thinking something like calculateAreaBySide() and calculateAreaByRadius(), to make it feel like the basic functionality had been overloaded... but you're right, that's not actually an overload.

The Method Signature must be UNIQUE. Therefore Java uses the method name and the parameter list, the return type is not considered. If you have two ident signatures, Java cannot determine which of the two to use.

To fix this, just rename each calculateArea method to reflect the shape it's calculating for, like calculateRectangleArea, calculateSquareArea, and calculateCircleArea, since Java got confused with all of them taking a single double as a parameter. The error happened because Java couldn't tell the methods apart just by their parameter names or return type.
The best thing to do would be to change the method names like this:
public static double calculateRectangleArea(double length, double width) {
    return length * width;
}

public static double calculateSquareArea(double side) {
    return side * side;
}

public static double calculateCircleArea(double radius) {
    return Math.PI * radius * radius;
}


What you are doing is not overloading, and won't compile.
There are two easy ways to correct this:
// Method to calculate the area of a square
    public static double calculateArea(double side) {
        return side * side;
    }

    // Method to calculate the area of a circle
    public static double calculateArea(double radius) {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

Option 1: give them unique names
// Method to calculate the area of a square
    public static double calculateAreaOfSquare(double side) {
        return side * side;
    }

    // Method to calculate the area of a circle
    public static double calculateAreaOfCircle(double radius) {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

or add a parameter, that defines what type you are looking for:
public enum Shape {
  CIRCLE,
  SQUARE;
} 

// Method to calculate the area of a shape
public static double calculateArea(double side, Shape shape) {
    if ( shape == Shape.SQUARE )
        return side * side;
    else if ( shape == Shape.CIRCLE )
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    throw new RuntimeException("Shape: " + shape.name() + " not supported");
}

